# Mocking a return value

Tags: java, mockito

I am using Mockito 1.9.5 to try and test a method. Here is the method:

```
@Autowire
AuditLogRepository auditlogRepository;

//method stuff abbreviated out

if (authentic.isAuthorized()) {
    menuService.updateUserWithMenu( authentic );
    AuditLog auditor = Helper.buildAuditor( authentic );
    auditor.setAccessPoint( request.getRequestURL().toString() );
    ....
    AuditLog createdAuditLog = auditlogRepository.save( auditor );
    logger.debug( "Created AuditLog id = " + createdAuditLog.getID() );
    ...

}
```

And here is how I am trying to test it:

```
@InjectMocks
LoginController loginController;

@Mock
AuditLog aLog;

@Mock
AuditLog createdAuditLog;

@Mock
AuditLogRepository auditlogRepositoryMock;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup( loginController ).build();
}

@Test    
public void testLogin() throws Exception {
    ...
    AuditLog aLog = mock( AuditLog.class );
    when( auditlogRepositoryMock.save( aLog ) ).thenReturn(createdAuditLog );
    when( createdAuditLog.getID() ).thenReturn( new Long( 1 ) );
```

It looks like no matter what I do, Mockito will always return null, except for primitives.  But my code is going to act upon a returned value.  So my question is there a way to test this without getting the null pointer?  Can Mockito return an object from a method call?

Comment: I'm still getting used to Mockito myself (only been using it for about 4 months) so I'll post this as a comment instead of an answer. I believe you are saying only return `createdAuditLog` when you call `save()` with the object (`aLog`). I have been using the `Matcher` class to setup when/thenReturns. Like this `when( auditlogRepositoryMock.save(Matchers.any(AuditLog.class)).thenReturn(createdAuditLog);`

Comment: yes, mockito can return objects, can you give more information about your nullpointer?

Comment: @Kyle from my point of view your comment is correct. When the method save is not called with the instance aLog the return will not be used and mockito uses his default behaviour. Without the complete code this is the best answer to give. So post it as answer ;).

Answer (score 1):

You have mocks for `AuditLog` as both a field and a local variable in your test, and I suspect neither is actually used in the code under test, since the `AuditLog` instance passed to your `auditlogRepositoryMock.save` call is actually created in the code under test by the call

```
AuditLog auditor = Helper.buildAuditor( authentic );
```

If you need to really control this argument from your test, you might need to change the code you're testing to allow that.

If you don't really care about the value of the `AuditLog` passed in, you can change your stub to use a  more permissive `Matcher`, possibly something like:

```
when( auditlogRepositoryMock.save( argThat(any(AuditLog.class)) ) ).thenReturn(createdAuditLog );
```

which should cause your repository mock to return the test value `createdAuditLog` for all calls of `save`.

Answer (score 0):

> Can Mockito return an object from a method call?

Yes, you can change the [Answers](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Answers.html) of the [@Mock](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mock.html) annotation from the default values `null` to return mocks, stubs, call the real methods or other behaviour, e.g.

```
@Mock(answer = RETURNS_MOCKS)
AuditLogRepository auditlogRepositoryMock;
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice,  I ended up using:
    when( auditlogRepositoryMock.save( Matchers.any( AuditLog.class ) ) ).thenReturn( createdAuditLog );  Because the @Mock(answer=RETURNS_MOCK) was returning a java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer$ClassWithSuperclassToWorkAroundCglibBug$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$463b1068 cannot be cast to com.edelweissco.dental.model.AuditLog